# AKOscillator frequency range for theremin sound in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I want to create similar sound to theremin using touch coordinate on screen. I'm using y axis as frequency, x axis as amplitude.

Due to my small research I believe I can create it using AKOscillator or AKFMOscillator from AudioKit framework (please let me know if any other oscillator works better in this case). I'm open to other frameworks like built-in AudioToolbox (MIDINoteMessage etc.) if I can create similar sound to theremin.

[Here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Electuredemonstrations/Composer/Pages/60.17.html#:%7E:text=How%20does%20it%20work%3F,range%20of%20257%2D260%20kHz.) it says theremin has two oscillators. One with fixed-frequency on 260kHz and one is dynamic between 257-260kHz. It superimposes their output (it takes difference of them I guess?). And it outputs between frequency between 0-3 kHz.
When I create sounds using AKFMOscillator with baseFrequency between 257-260 kHz, it sounds high-pitched.
When I try with one oscillator range between 0-3kHz it sounds very robotic. How I can simulate timbre of theremin?

How can I make it sound better? Should I mix two oscillators? I tried mixing with AKMixer but when both oscillators use same frequency and amplitude, it makes no difference.
I tried to mapping to nearest note (auto-tune), I tried limiting the frequency between 3-4 octaves. It sounds better but still not good as theremin.
What should use ( AKOscillator or AKFMOscillator, OscillatorBank), with which parameters (rampDuration, baseFrequency, modulationIndex, amplitude) to simulate more thereminish sound?

Update:
I did some more research and played with Synth One presets. Now, I know I need two oscillators mixed (both set to saw-shape wave). Changing ADSR(envelope) values to specific ranges creates richer sound (this gives the instrumental sound type). And a lfo to create the wavy (or spooky) sound effect. Playing notes (specific frequencies) creates good sounds, if you play every frequency in between note frequencies it doesn't sound good.

Comment: The article says the range is from 65 Hz to about 3 kHz, not 257 to 260 kHz, that's the frequency range of the variable-frequency oscillator.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I missed that part in the article. I will try with that frequency.

Comment: I updated the question @TamásSengel. Could you have a look it again?